# I want to call two opposing onclick events in one button. For example, I want the first click to add an item to cart and the next to remove the item

Tags: javascript, dom-events, shopping-cart

```
<button onclick = "addToCart(); removeFromCart()" type="button" class="prodCartbutton">ADD TO CART </button>
```

This will only makes it run simultaneously. I want to add items to cart on the first click. Remove the same item on the second link. Add again on the third click and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use boolean logic to alternate states between true and false. That way a function only fires when its state matches the variable's state.

initially set outside of the functions:

```
let shopState = false;
```

then you can conditionally call your functions.

```
const addToCart = (shopState) => {
   if (shopState === false){
      ...what you want to execute...
   }
   shopState = true;
}

//AND

const removeFromCart = (shopState) => {
   if (shopState !== true){
      ...what you want to execute...
   }
   shopState = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to create an intermediate function that manages these events with a counter to decide which other function to call.